# Huawei E160 Wireless Dongle appears as a drive?

Tags: hardware, broadband

I have just purchased a Huawei E160 dongle on o2 which, I was told works on Ubuntu and other Linux operating systems however everytime i plug it in it loads as a drive and i cannot get to install the software from it?

There is an EXE file which will not open so how can I get it to work?
It works on windows perfectly?

Comment: Do you also have a memory card in the dongle? I know from experience this model has an MiniSD card reader built it?

Comment: Yes it does and yes I have. Is that an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drive you are seeing on your desktop is the USB card reader that is built into the modem device and should not effect the use of the modem.

To set up this device for Internet usage please do the following...

1) Click on the network icon at the top right of the screen

2) Go down to `Edit Connections....`

3) Click on Mobile Broadband

4) Click Add

You should see a setup dialogue with the option to use HUAWEI Technology HUAWEI Mobile.
Follow the instructions in this setup remembering to double check the information you select such as your provider, as you said it is o2 and the type of plan you have wither pay as you go or contract etc.

Once you have done this click save.

Once saved you should have a new option under your network icon for Mobile Broadband. Simply click on the new connection and away you go!

Comment: I done this but for some reason it did not save my information? I had to run the setup program twice for it to work.

Comment: I had the same problem with my Mobile Dongle at first. If you have two connections simply go into Edit Connections again and delete the one that has the word 'never' under last used.